# Confusion matrix for 4D array of multiclass image segmentation

Tags: python, numpy, image-segmentation, confusion-matrix

The results from my multi-class image segmentation gives a 4d array like `(25, 512, 512, 4)`, what would be the best way to create a confusion matrix with the actual class labels (that has the same array dimensions)?

I thought about flattening each class axis and using argmax to return the index (aka class label), to get a 1D array of prediction class labels. But this seems really inefficient so hoping someone has a better idea.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the predicted segmentation, `25`x`512`x`512`x`4`? Is it a batch of 25 images of shape 512x512 pixels with 4 semantic classes?

Comment: There are 25 images, where each image has a height and width of 512 pixels, and 4 semantic classes.

Comment: For the actual class labels, I would expect an array of size `25`x`512`x`512` with values in the range `[0...3]`. Why do you have "the same array dimensions" for the actual classes? What values are stored in this array?